# Optimize Matplotlib plot that dynamically updates and remains interactive

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, plot, multiprocessing

Ok, so as the *question* suggests, I am chasing the best method to create a plot that:

1)   Is independent of the main program/script, therefore making changes to the plot will have no adverse (locking or other) effect on the main program/script

2)   Can be interacted with via matplotlib's default GUI or other custom GUI

**Now, what I have so far for the above criteria:**

1)   Use the multiprocessing module and its multiprocessing Queue to pass X,Y information to a separate process that appends to current X,Y data and refreshes the plot. **This basically addresses criteria 1.**

2)   Ensuring matplotlib's interactive mode is turned on (ion()), an infinite `while True:` loop checks the aforementioned queue and if there is no X,Y information, allow's processing of GUI events via `pyplot.pause(interval in seconds)`

To simplify things, below is my code to accept incoming X,Y data and plot it in pseudocode. This code is run in a different process with a Queue feeding it X,Y data.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

def run(self):

  p = pyplot 

        while True:
            if there's nothing in the Queue:
                redraw and allow GUI events (p.pause(0.0001))
                continue
            else:
                command = get X,Y info from Queue

                if command equals X,Y data:

                    update plots x data (axes.set_ydata())
                    update plots y data (axes.set_ydata())

                    update axis data limits (axes.relim())
                    update axis view limits (axes.autoscale_view())

                    redraw and allow GUI events i.e. interaction for 0.0001 seconds (p.pause(0.0001))

                elif if command equals the "exit loop" value:
                    break

        turn of interactive mode (p.ioff())
        keep plot open and block process until closed by user (p.show())
```

So can the above be optimized to increase interactivity with the figure GUI? potentially by allowing GUI events to be serviced independently of the plot being updated? This method becomes slower the more updates it has to do (i.e. if there are more plots on the same figure to update)

Any clarifications, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the x,y-data via queue (as already planned), but would use the get-command in combination with the block-argument. That way, your drawing-function blocks until there are elements in the queue. If there are not, the function pauses and all other events in your application can be processed.

Something like that:

```
def process_data(inqueue):
    #create your plot

    for infile in iter(inqueue.get(block=True), "STOP"):
        #update plot until inqueue.get returns "STOP"
        #waits for elements in the queue enter code here

def main():
    inqueue = Queue()
    process = Process(target=process_data, args=(inqueue,)
    #can be stopped by putting "STOP" via inqueue.put into the queue
    process.start()
    #put some data in the queue
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment mate. If there are no items in Queue, wouldn't it lock up the Figure's GUI until the Queue unblocks? That's how I understood Queues and their blocking anyway haha

Comment: I don't know. I would assume that the GUI is handled elsewhere while the update functions blocks. However, I would just test it..